# High availability in two node Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, replication, high-availability

We have a requirement to run highly available Elasticsearch cluster with only two nodes. I understand for reliable HA it is recommended to have odd number of nodes (3+) but cannot do that because of some particular environment restrictions.

In ES 6.x we could achieve that by setting `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` config option to 1, this allows to keep remaining node UP in case of single node failure ( https://blog.trifork.com/2013/10/24/how-to-avoid-the-split-brain-problem-in-elasticsearch/ ). This comes at cost of potential data inconsistency but that's something we know how to deal with.

Now, in ES 7.x. `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` option has no effect anymore. Is there any way to achieve similar behavior with ES 7.x on two node cluster, i.e. keep high availability at cost of losing some data integrity when split-brain occurs?

Comment: split-brain may cause a massive data loss (happened to me). I don't understand what is benefit of HA when the possibility of losing data is very high?

Comment: I was trying to find an answer to this question as well. The documentation [seems to suggest](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/high-availability-cluster-small-clusters.html#high-availability-cluster-design-two-nodes) that a two-node set up can be configured in a "primary-replica" style and can handle the failure of the  replica node. What isn't clear to me is what would happen on failure of the primary and how long (if at all) the replica can take over

Comment: @atomic77 doc says "The cluster can tolerate the loss of the other master-ineligible node" i.e. the loss of "replica". If master goes down, entire cluster is down, replica won't take over without user intervention.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this excellent [blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-new-era-for-cluster-coordination-in-elasticsearch) that explains in detail about the changes in cluster co-ordination in ES 7.x

Per the [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_cluster_bootstrapping_is_required_if_discovery_is_configured), `The discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes setting is permitted, but ignored, on 7.x nodes.` Instead you configure `discovery.seed_hosts` and `cluster.initial_master_nodes` as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/discovery-settings.html#initial_master_nodes).